# MySQL PHPMyAdmin error #2002

Tags: mysql

*NOTE: I have read loads of other posts on this, however the majority of them were from 4+ years ago, so I guess you can render them out of date.

*NOTE 2: This problem applies to trying to view PHP files with my testing server as well, I literally can't do anything when this error occurs.

Basically, I have been unable to use my Wamp testing server for the past two days because of this problem. I know for a fact that re-installing Wampserver fixes this, however it goes back to giving me this error once I restart my computer, meaning I have to re-install Wamp and then re-make my databases every time I restart my computer.
It's starting to become really irritating, and I have looked everywhere for a valid answer.

This is the error:

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Not a php issue, but alas, Have you tried to disable your firewall to see if this is the cause?

Comment: Yes I did, it did not fix my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Have you checked the log files? Is MySQL showing in your services?

Comment: Could this be my problem? [06-Oct-2015 08:11:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: That should not be related.  In MySQL, `SELECT @@ERROR_LOG;`.  This will give you the path to the log file you probably need to open up and read.  Of course, you need to already know this value before the problem occurs.